# In firebase hosting configuration, how do I write a rule to redirect all sources except one while capturing the url segment?

Tags: firebase, redirect, firebase-hosting

Setting up a firebase hosting project, I'd like to redirect all requests except for one to another domain and retain the url segment in the redirect. For example `example.com/page` should redirect to `www.example.com/page`, while anything starting with `example.com/ignore` should not redirect.

In firebase.json, I wrote this rule to redirect any request not in the ignore path:

```
"redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/!(ignore)",
        "destination": "https://www.example.com/",
        "type": 302
      }
    ]
```

This redirect works, however I want to capture any url segments in the redirect. I'm trying to followed the example from their docs where `:post*` is the url segment I want to retain, but I do not know how to write it in the redirect rules.

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "redirects": [ {
    "source": "/blog/:post*",  // captures the entire URL segment beginning at "post"
    "destination": "https://blog.myapp.com/:post", // includes the entire URL segment identified and captured by the "source" value
    "type": 301
  }
```

I have also tried the following which works to capture the url segment in redirect, but also redirects my ignored path as well.

```
"redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/:path*",
        "destination": "https://www.example.com/:path",
        "type": 302
      }
    ]
```

I've also tried the above snippet with the ignore folder added to the ignore rules and this did not work either.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/ignore/**"
    ],
...
}
```

I'd like to be able write a glob pattern to capture any path that doesn't match the ignore path and use that in the redirect, something like:

```
"source": "/!(ignore)**path**,
"destination: "https://www.example.com/**path**",
"type": 302
```